# nerd dinner map being displayed out of the container div

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, jquery, nerddinner

I am implementing the nerd dinner example in MVC2. The problem which I am having is with the map. The map which is Ajax enabled does not display properly on the webpage i.e. the actual map is shown out of the div element inside of which it should actually be displaying.

```
            <div id="mapDiv">
              <% Html.RenderPartial("Map", Model.Dinner); %>
            </div>
```

The above is the code in my dinner form which call my Map.ascx . Map.ascx calls the loadmap function which comes from the Map.js and these files have been directly copied from the guide book. I have tried opening the form in different browsers but the map is still out of place.

I have checked the code but seem to be missing some very small detail. Any help would be much appreciated for this noob problem. Sorry unable to upload pics because of less "reputation" points.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I have marked below reply as the answer , please have a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an article here http://forums.asp.net/t/1569315.aspx/1 . Give it try, and see how it works...